# Rails, Mongoid: Why isn't find_or_create_by saving something?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

So this is a pretty simple issue.

I am playing around with MongoDB and mongoid and I am using the method find_or_create_by.

I have a very simple model called Post that has a title, body, and starred fields in it.

Here is my code:

```
@test = Post.find_or_create_by(title: '123')
```

Now there isn't a Post with a title 123 in my database. When I run this it creates a new Post object to me with the title of 123, but it isn't being saved to the database...

What am I missing?

Thanks for your help.

David

Comment: Do you have any validations on your model? Is `@test.valid?` true after you create the model? How are you testing if there is a corresponding `Post` record in the DB?

Comment: Oooh...I do have validations! That was it!! To check and see if the record is in the DB I am using robomongo to look at the tables directly. You need to answer the question officially so I can give you credit! Thanks.